# In an Android app, how do I make a linear view with transparent text so that the parent view is visible?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, alpha-transparency

Any ideas on how to make a view containing some text transparent so that it overlaps on top another view?

[Here's an example image of what im referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkKBG.jpg)

I'm trying to create a feature to display the bio of a user in the chat page just like that of Whatsapp messenger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use next Code

```
  <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="16sp"
       android:textColor="#fff"
       android:text="Your text "
       android:paddingTop="8dp"
       android:paddingBottom="8dp"
       android:textAlignment="center"
       android:background="#60000000"
/>
```

You can add the above XML in any view you are using for example next view

```
                <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">
                
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="#343"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                 <!--                        more views here -->
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:text="Your text "
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:background="#60000000"
                    />
            </FrameLayout>
```